# Multiple added entities may have the same primary key in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working in a project using EF 4.0.

The `Employee` table has a column `ReferEmployeeID` which contains the employee id of the employee that is referring a new employee in the system. So `Employee` is a self-referencing table.

Now in the case of an employee who is not added to the system is about to add and he also refers another employee in the system, the row should be added altogether.

`ActualEmployee` save not called yet and then `ReferEmployee.Employee = ActualEmployee`

I understand the issue is that both the employees actual and refer has Employee ID set to 0, but how to come around this problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Assuming that the `EmployeeID` in your database table is defined as `INT IDENTITY`, then you could do this:

```
// create two new employees - one refers to the other
Employee john = new Employee { EmployeeID = -1, EmpName = "John" };
Employee peter = new Employee { EmployeeID = -2, EmpName = "Peter", ReferEmployeeID = -1 };

// add them to the EF model
ctx.AddToEmployees(john);
ctx.AddToEmployees(peter);

// save changes
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

So basically, define your new employees with "dummy" `EmployeeID` values and establish the link (`Peter` references `John` here, by means of its "dummy" ID).

When saving this into SQL Server, the Entity Framework will handle the process of getting the *real* `EmployeeID` values (which SQL Server hands out when inserting the row) and EF will maintain that link between the two employees.

Comment: I've been hunting for this answer for about two hours. I never knew EF worked that way (using dummy identities). Is that documented or discussed anywhere? Thanks!

Comment: @Mike: not sure - I picked it up somewhere along the lines, reading books, blogs and intro videos by Julie Lerman and the EF team