# Entity Framework 6.1: Multiple added entities may have the same primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm running into an issue with Entity Framework, and this is the error: `Unable to determine the principal end of the 'Force.Data.Models.Employee_Office' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.` I can't figure out what the issue is and I've been staring at it for three hours now. Here's the code, could someone point me in the right direction because I can't seem to:

**Employee.cs**

```
public partial class Employee : Person, IUser<int> {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    #region Relationship Properties
    public byte CompanyId { get; set; }
    public short OfficeId { get; set; }
    public int? ManagerId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; private set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Device> Devices { get; private set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Email> Emails { get; private set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; private set; }
    public virtual Employee Manager { get; set; }
    public virtual Office Office { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phones { get; private set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; private set; }
    #endregion
}
```

**Office.cs**

```
public partial class Office {
    public short Id { get; set; }

    #region Relationship Properties
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public short RegionId { get; set; }

    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; private set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; private set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Lead> Leads { get; private set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phones { get; private set; }
    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

**EmployeeConfiguration.cs**

```
internal sealed class EmployeeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Employee> {
    public EmployeeConfiguration() {
        this.ToTable("Employees");

        this.HasKey(
            k =>
                k.Id);

        #region Properties
        #endregion

        #region Relationships
        /// Employee has a 1:* relationship with Offices.
        this.HasRequired(
            t =>
                t.Office).WithMany(
            t =>
                t.Employees).HasForeignKey(
            k =>
                k.OfficeId);
        #endregion
    }
}
```

**OfficeConfiguration.cs**

```
internal sealed class OfficeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Office> {
    public OfficeConfiguration() {
        this.ToTable("Offices");

        this.HasKey(
            k =>
                k.Id);

        #region Properties
        this.Property(
            p =>
                p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        #endregion

        #region Relationships
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Here's also a screenshot of the generated database, which looks fine to me. I don't think it's the database that's yelling at me, but rather EF beinc confused about something...

[image]

Comment: When and where does the exception occur?

Comment: On `SaveChanges` when the context is initializing the database, I think.

Comment: You may have the same problem with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530581/multiple-added-entities-may-have-the-same-primary-key-in-entity-framework

Comment: It doesn't look like any of the code posted is at fault. Post whatever is trying to add an office / employee and save changes.

Comment: You're right, I'm an idiot, look at my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I'm an idiot, the problem was looking at me this whole time... It turned out it was the `Seed` method that was failing. In it I was adding 40 `Employee` objects, but one of them did not have an `Office` assigned to it and that's why it was failing. Ugh, I need a nap...